# Python testing if my data follows a lognormal distribution

Tags: python, scipy

Hi I have a distribution of results that is positively skewed so I want to test if it is a good fit to a log-normal distribution or a Gumbell distribution.

I have used scipy before so I would be particularly interested in a solution that uses that.

My data is as follows:

```
listofdata =[2.6631285853098805, 1.948723030911822, 0.7325723211390256, 2.2214185217697033, 3.1973557053902932, 2.721464385217916, 6.047370467406893, 2.1765253837023133, 1.306088411159033, 2.037397915785744, 0.6862715889678953, 1.6537292516821143, 0.6817011291422773, 0.60568083550246, 3.4541516258461225, 1.656598441242852, 0.9973472121207236, 3.994828136966692, 1.2493128240123388, 1.318803895196777, 1.8219708475333733, 1.7803822001562708, 3.5163486988690806, 1.4751609825413308, 0.9884113209191469, 1.2980162786357938, 6.113447232418334, 1.3977589458544686, 1.3801647781025739, 1.590725233816818, 1.1810871981759308, 0.8465477721823732, 3.840200049154681, 1.7554665652380321, 1.5723775058591742, 4.500040304113793, 3.160488460719387, 1.3047308289360104, 2.274979276414489, 0.9723041606774018, 1.1567129068539885, 2.5565846148750895, 2.207555444411525, 3.9312893279475367, 0.9645189125969524, 2.335251067183356, 2.137155238698881, 1.692118350167095, 3.7484654065657317, 2.462059088568015, 1.709511478987372, 5.715634836586185, 4.007251296312767, 0.7920956096185022, 2.022714463787213, 3.6688048370106, 2.403327178013035, 1.3352007066736067, 1.66939693318501, 2.874196897009085, 1.1881850454957774, 2.579568121065461, 3.5966255826677638, 3.6845567419377976, 1.811342042134277, 2.72660313403154, 1.5281549016493845, 3.0009286822719448, 1.9066586300548696, 1.458152722378702, 4.3986928824471185, 2.469956971757018, 2.234841611733566, 2.167520317680794, 2.8227039648170944, 2.1680491069116337, 2.791952773940272, 2.7561204297857445, 3.864343552457842, 4.163309180742488, 1.3885516350912332, 1.5804900958284296, 1.7802071358399305, 1.053751762721538, 1.4606173223348946, 1.6396991782893227, 3.975995706374045, 1.7069750915722237, 2.7394711066762856, 2.932233687553241, 2.801765372352213, 1.8055086910114486, 4.386319520417248, 6.231899492086985, 1.9099936593860443, 1.4623481604454012, 1.6664581852371045, 0.9640381031320316, 3.798087950415322, 5.941754430001641, 0.6396615233190119, 1.6475205547422664, 0.9206837382120625, 1.13649665702186, 3.190532670519826, 1.8179993080793222, 1.2883848748915967, 1.6886913583637237, 3.0253353325933525, 2.5459601801373424, 3.553558930272823, 3.0167019019366195, 2.093910031934536, 2.387012247818087, 6.599382663248629, 2.2250434798564247, 2.217618989085747, 5.029331918631793, 3.8614067384474655, 1.5238916754723622, 1.4413941704278046, 3.7037545029041326, 1.3380847555974584, 2.81986125570312, 1.6722094303958446, 0.8333766382783666, 3.415118103622843, 0.9638789362679631, 1.0872082475073852, 0.653371376107782, 1.9328274820705817, 5.719890351366793, 3.727756437255686, 4.013921036687349, 5.274583205793386, 5.075972778513814, 3.2332547305133743, 4.784095191295217, 1.749928666320386, 0.9466632533417737, 1.7473617554197174, 1.7327087344009329, 4.254653689587041, 2.704724201264992, 1.302947557035884, 4.544662425542001, 1.7359099700035927, 3.762424742225096, 3.2821877078112833, 2.3782263261571073, 5.100654633325338, 4.066351496553931, 3.97552948329211, 2.5951057372086663, 1.7714901372033298, 1.525460925528444, 4.751135330410933, 1.8478272067456718, 4.522860286225603, 1.33108096647635, 1.4631079480345421, 3.3889471890043175, 5.375750765463488, 1.572192614906169, 1.8849615994731381, 2.1640833393579335, 1.400734015801129, 1.199408997635476, 1.283800021440095, 3.969005754593775, 4.688120068063393, 0.6094648531043163, 1.3376356639533813, 1.4298774989278287, 1.682937405662949, 1.5503814228713855, 5.1908910399526915, 3.3491293091840024, 1.6974575131253573, 1.9853315310458242, 2.1905668019808564, 1.8187658425231694, 1.4888560838650278, 2.0158070339920764, 2.0791245525913955, 1.8269910833823249, 1.376401604937098, 2.9200172207676696, 1.4064524965873375, 3.933919109117903, 1.6981680652230462, 0.9253776818632217, 3.425663590986357, 2.4371772991536425, 1.3415420778437126, 2.5286957289128504, 1.5631285450027126, 2.3792763267009724, 2.112288439090446, 0.853331930788329, 3.01387170836307, 3.868024990596985, 2.3046965854680486, 1.4412029778159994, 3.9219205615541917, 4.912245175829266, 1.5603334400589013, 2.060750001743202, 2.2176605660206063, 2.1638446665173547, 6.069381531603165, 1.4174522634614846, 2.6557438655852477, 2.3035186997719967, 3.4088606969399393, 3.8218576477085096, 0.9220973744491742, 2.7727867248032334, 3.5597658039422537, 1.0705020358064419, 2.446479128826161, 5.8158612152005515, 1.7227692291642485, 1.2786263253762058, 1.094889840451913, 2.004283509510617, 2.4416686355784467, 5.001676036540756, 1.7314916420110538, 1.0192792374065558, 1.376025503501194, 1.9554409006370301, 2.911617211807391, 6.058430670167684, 1.3812081238895986, 4.525492684961262, 3.0477125394845994, 0.9271038124867458, 2.965930100533376, 2.143607628397433, 3.2324344761887347, 3.7712935020551077, 1.1845418838483626, 1.2951075263854706, 2.640592456495699, 1.1492445590222249, 2.139926413691671, 1.415089804907359, 1.001728381293617, 2.9862128133023242, 1.722988802145494, 2.7998080908644276, 2.069879670956732, 2.763383217528315, 2.321711598999366, 4.3227378002122006, 1.5810984288128, 3.076173072407175, 2.3282175076493217, 1.2022065905379693, 1.769249151091106, 1.6128692411271346, 1.379811277656916, 2.7008791469980555, 3.039836410984219, 1.3679957379842678, 3.0028470634866715, 2.9206849757337867, 1.4454681539613488, 2.3185725366247314, 2.2148330412723114, 2.1522529057362476, 4.12832262797084, 4.276295290166637, 1.1908214069483278, 1.6615379521658384, 0.9022115996830166, 5.312270194426526, 2.5121965619024538, 1.7550141990482993, 1.9771937741057517, 2.5367219088304527, 1.3631537379612273, 4.301202799295913, 2.046943419762249, 3.3237322475962516, 2.0978315839682526, 2.973408753252409, 3.4607880004390497, 3.4569611078641524, 2.237036802429213, 5.996833779655401, 2.620377791494286, 1.4514003425523585, 4.432585331847452, 6.890304980819486, 4.708229269332186, 2.683235474594801, 1.393334095590592, 2.1876660156460845, 1.715925142349704, 4.496556395378718, 1.0899670522676954, 1.3555804411348507, 1.6257532470905858, 1.1305247113980272, 1.3973829944943303, 1.4514613497570399, 4.416290665552117, 4.670174218054661, 1.455709899721808, 2.8568093861539525, 2.549283449230063, 1.523048849798295, 0.776152455009981, 1.1927682656178262, 1.4698682343959604, 0.9268397464195571, 2.1434126568063565, 1.1031837372307678, 2.2013642799807367, 3.89474349953697, 1.3835302910509315, 2.328532153978324, 2.3652662157964532, 1.460171504244943, 2.353475705620087, 6.505381032718413, 1.0627882008788103, 1.481573631085678, 2.135527174377069, 2.097130442026503, 1.0554115389981575, 1.3683875605618936, 6.058430670167684, 1.413608877073841, 0.9163216347346066, 2.2169974272656985, 1.491360564704439, 2.2610376866959654, 0.9996350752044578, 3.082605699458043, 1.1805687265794973, 1.3244957400729278, 1.7612812885785958, 0.7201988411797062, 1.893224708694436, 0.8953041203583892, 1.1970462872638223, 2.382324056346477, 1.9433581408100171, 3.0426055429459553, 2.98659983050751, 2.041207210280311, 3.113805787569811, 2.8152908162760584, 2.133493802789269, 1.062025175014912, 1.9187070234303867, 3.039891409580889, 2.842364992201135, 3.0964741881318454, 1.325725951307561, 1.6139351127268926, 2.0964970963061775, 6.094065297595637, 1.9328960213975168, 0.8643295749025923, 1.4574352176412393, 0.8829513097988297, 1.7000672527406895, 4.969916526049599, 2.0098709212613244, 1.8295321928593353, 2.9767045248525736, 5.094576736772535, 1.6897634221302613, 2.7251772959355436, 2.668543530304771, 3.818645906555901, 1.5801536429044638, 2.267034140667636, 4.215234687025543, 1.082202224737796, 2.0533223399257743, 1.2580587946235826, 1.1993837400744838, 1.4873982438211786, 1.441834660966117, 1.1333851437009688, 1.2650447265844944, 2.1434218190387244, 1.4636742455652325, 1.1237341223973887, 4.254700905473931, 2.5883325431123354, 1.5009640100274624, 0.8640023787861196, 2.10057993883928, 6.23023641387366, 2.3394033877896057, 2.054202713804114, 2.2471673823043266, 0.8697105719270324, 2.5736959967597044, 1.5968034536981917, 1.9360852185713497, 2.207347119502118, 5.995124760786587, 2.3184067425093993, 3.7792955774416104, 2.5600355259438516, 2.063983561817452, 2.1762570501494904, 1.9545853743984374, 1.284400919767211, 1.113409023729889, 6.925691011137326, 2.3341975139709237, 0.8958568879715244, 2.8300657056369234, 1.5028745032136048, 1.234165494499155, 0.8726718755983369, 1.518786148775064, 1.6584564684852126, 3.727613206060198, 3.2677276129035024, 2.72620420011582, 2.1128179320322604, 1.284251736220551, 2.0414978371537824, 4.499862707847422, 1.597854901409971, 1.7453554200318762, 1.7718980536944515, 1.8213597882243564, 6.925691011137326, 3.267712843906213, 1.4599115046304525, 2.298227722215677, 1.2714446242676447, 1.5638811171853495, 1.3669668521364768, 2.2204318393208844, 2.8243994341950276, 2.044273083814221, 1.9899375494728138, 1.4368589390064357, 1.332446098309913, 1.2156754847339364, 6.233075393442153, 1.8298441247714783, 6.1823442730375415, 1.4379664358797641, 4.1257007707626485, 1.9044630711575907, 2.470553995968077, 5.866250292601297, 1.255662181816604, 1.5140048525842649, 2.657060232661468, 2.778908460715467, 4.231890673028045, 5.931473602301425, 2.68535304385847, 1.4343877983634117, 1.3679492613277606, 3.004958007907305, 2.7087570724571948, 2.915722773553568, 1.0355520668809162, 0.9224800557295452, 2.494795916039982, 2.2348421734045703, 1.6201077679873268, 2.7813118895693942, 1.198310995491613, 2.3040660679490537, 1.2932237171327532, 2.834421862128772, 1.387968872040949, 1.024888336344895, 1.370532116447396, 2.6421835520219816, 1.307180593341525, 3.007495630469009, 2.876374021350295, 1.242985291946491, 1.3809912706970524, 4.38616276706074, 1.3962400102325887, 4.148812526715677, 0.7690549533611034, 3.500610634498923, 0.6946915612824682, 3.7250741821763427, 1.477922330517788, 3.1116113270191703, 4.16246893729159, 3.087825061769616, 3.600963894162931, 5.093131858053347, 2.6177087969890294, 3.514093669751753, 1.8414608524694474, 1.4842151016706226, 2.7202701086573478, 3.454150906498137, 1.6986509194055657, 1.3237619954001847, 1.408311312479748, 4.293873222920515, 2.8337402354759322, 1.5382438398514413, 2.7071429486111462, 2.0743820281228986, 1.0654447643277418, 3.9570723319709376, 1.0235266820133686, 1.0019799701700438, 0.8022216046489916, 2.598136255775342, 3.5704954064092025, 2.50573097683083, 6.241715435280128, 0.9617848446586663, 2.789996754666902, 2.34290795966932, 1.0746084576917496, 2.9484305982585175, 2.7462636109212664, 1.5188419792977246, 2.054685248073509, 2.365927360649732, 1.9494668145689167, 2.9421449628084586, 1.5185140216743662, 2.573136048496998, 4.354862282941338, 1.3234907145399237, 2.54964139539378, 3.142802328924847, 2.6709728331131712, 4.438413270023023, 3.7200423628230848, 3.8223619809512575, 4.5367727771413575, 1.019930017485342, 1.3660281441774373, 2.1669618687480696, 5.68366536642535, 4.551469748029795, 3.330198375677071, 3.4241899352978296, 1.4409221435878752, 1.92152191393692, 5.303429640376464, 0.8902493656335649, 0.8484118348433071, 3.140582424364573, 3.85601499325702, 2.4330666696369803, 6.058431338539675, 4.185483681795529, 4.396912357632606, 3.1985724580568213, 1.2622032913354244, 5.071286922400795, 1.3577349076124052, 0.8386698665930794, 1.583960030146625, 2.3165090264333568, 2.4268724248578684, 1.3103225230814022, 2.848158441342469, 1.5830995853818086, 1.623850822661541, 4.131845973675001, 3.6583424474137143, 3.256075028727502, 1.378949943606347, 1.1548851827309252, 4.042005794764293, 0.8767602008278913, 2.0588224565452387, 2.769542660383933, 2.7389826447953625, 1.847221632704498, 1.988084035898203, 2.5996665022037986, 1.7318042565547218, 2.2037727392705513, 3.8471428538245505, 2.430388568655724, 0.9944268869340591, 1.4952205655327475, 4.843766010646061, 1.1086439860938186, 1.826784919886825, 1.3055612039004134, 2.2404340831671905, 1.2729546869394994, 1.7632930086409375, 1.6919598475253337, 2.946514032261155, 1.7605124901475733, 1.4434407191536027, 1.010622271635282, 1.2895021199482586, 1.3175421234935245, 2.526015815718631, 2.4642424103584175, 1.1973702301666782, 2.2325460171325524, 1.6168912451241, 1.7498546608031689, 2.098356053647092, 3.314708785562868, 2.4571380603389907, 2.07546261668025, 1.2223602012291284, 2.3280094595669305]
```

I have cut down the list due to the character limit. However the distribution should look like this:

[image: data that I want to fit against lognormal distribution]

EDIT: How would I quantitatively find how 'suitable' the data is to the distribution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can simply use `scipy.stats.lognorm.fit` to fit your data to a lognormal distribution. This will give you a tuple

```
(0.60845558877160033, 0.27409944344131409, 1.8037732130179509)
```

which represents shape, location, and scale respectively. If you want the more common parameters of mu and sigma, you can obtain them like so

```
shape, location, scale = scipy.stats.lognorm.fit(listofdata)
mu, sigma = np.log(scale), shape
```

You can use the `scipy.stats.gumbel_l.fit` function similarily for that respective distribution, which will return the location and scale.

As far as how to test goodness of fit for each distribution, one possibility would be to use the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test with [`scipy.stats.kstest`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kstest.html).

Comment: Thanks! But how do I assess the goodness of fit i.e. how suitable the data is for a lognormal distribution?

Comment: You can use Kolmogorov-Smirnov test: `scipy.stats.kstest(listofdata, "lognorm", scipy.stats.lognorm.fit(listofdata))` http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kstest.html

Comment: Also note that for the KS test probabilities to be accurate, the model must be independent from the data that one is trying to fit. In other words, either the model needs to be derived from another data set or other means in order for the KS Test to accurately determine the goodness of fit of the candidate model to the data that one wants to model. https://asaip.psu.edu/Articles/beware-the-kolmogorov-smirnov-test