# Python - Test if my data follow a Poisson/Exponential distribution

Tags: python, statistics, distribution, exponential-distribution

my question is very close to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795949/python-testing-if-my-data-follows-a-lognormal-distribution) but I would like to have more details.

I have some data and I want to check the amount of error I would have if I assume that these data follow an exponential/Poisson distribution (I'd like to have the parameters estimate if possible).

On the X axis I have a measure of probability (it is often close to 0 and rarely close to 1).

[image: Data]

Could you help me?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If someone is interested in the same question, [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/328803/python-test-if-my-data-follow-a-poisson-exponential-distribution) can find the answer.